# Tunnel or Bridge to Get to Windsor Train Station

Tags: canada, borders, detroit

Two other travelers and I are catching the 5:45 train from Windsor to Toronto this Friday. We are coming from Detroit and are wondering whether it is better to plan on taking the tunnel bus over or have a fourth person drive us over the bridge and drop us off at the station.

I'm worried about how much time to give for crossing the boarder and getting to the train station since it's going to be during rush hour. In addition, I'm not sure how much extra effort it is to go from the tunnel station to the train station. Similarly, I am not sure if it is not suspicious to have a friend say that they're dropping three people off at the train station and then coming back at the boarder.

My questions are:
1. How much time does it take to cross during peak rush-hour for either method 
2. How difficult is it to have a fourth person drive to the station and drop us off and how long does it take
3. How difficult is it to get from the tunnel station in Windsor to the train station and how long does it take

Comment: You may find [border wait times](https://cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/bwt-taf/menu-eng.html) helpful for planning purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I've been keeping an eye on it, but I figure Friday at 4-5 or so might be a bit exceptional.

Comment: Ah, I suppose you mean 5:45 pm? I had a hard time picturing 5 am being rush hour...

Comment: Google Maps recommends using bus line 2 from the Tunnel Bus stop at McDougall & Wyandotte to Wyandotte & Monmouth, from where you still have 5 good minutes walk to the train station. The whole trip duration depends a lot on where you are starting from. Do you have much luggage to carry?

Comment: Not too much to carry. Yes, 5:45 pm. If it's only a 5 minute walk, we should be fine to trek it.